# Having trouble processing XML with PHP SimpleXML

Tags: simplexml

http://pastie.org/1701923  Here is the XML being returned from an API I am querying for zip codes.

I want to pull the  data out of each entry and either loop it directly or put it into an array that I can loop. I can't seem to get it right.  Here is the latest code I was using:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($results);
foreach($xml->zipcoderadius->zipcodes as $loc) {
    $codes[] = (string)$loc['zipcode'];
}
print_r($codes);
die();
```

($results is the returned XML from CURL)

What is being output is Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => )

Answer (score 0):

I think this was,n be a string (zipcode). Try without string

Comment: Thanks. No change, the result is Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => )

(used a different zip code in the call, thus more results)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you're addressing the zip code correctly. For me the following works, assuming you stored your cURL result in `$xmlStr` previously.

```
$push = array();
$foo = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
foreach($foo->zipcoderadius->zipcodes->id as $bar) {
    array_push($push, (string)$bar);
}
print_r($push);
```

Leading to the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 75969
    [1] => 75970
    [2] => 75971
)
```

By the way: the SimpleXML object looks like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["zipcoderadius"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
    ["zipcodes"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (32) {
      ["id"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "75969"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "75970"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "75971"
      }
      ["zipcode"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "94945"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "94945"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "94945"
      }
...
```